Correct CMAKE arguments for custom LTO pass
I am trying to adapt the makefile presented here: https://github.com/EnzymeAD/Enzyme/issues/710 into a CMake file.
Background: My library uses Enzyme AD system for lto generation of gradients. And on Linux it works fine. When I am trying to compile it on Mac OS I get error that --lto-legacy-pass-manager is not a known option. The link above highlights the solution in the form of Makefile. How can I convert it to Cmake?
My Linux CMake relevant section is given below:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(libdescriptor)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
# Find enzyme at location ENZYME_LIB
string(REGEX MATCH "^[0-9]+" LLVM_MAJOR_VERSION ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION})
message("LLVM major version used: ${LLVM_MAJOR_VERSION}")

message("Searching for ENZYME at ${ENZYME_LIB}")
if(EXISTS "${ENZYME_LIB}/LLDEnzyme-${LLVM_MAJOR_VERSION}.dylib")
    message("Found LLDEnzyme plugin.")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "LLDEnzyme plugin not found, please check your Enzyme installation.")
endif()

# Set LLD, just in case... sometimes default LLD the name of LLD file is lld-12
if (NOT DEFINED LLD)
    set(LLD "lld")
endif()

# Compile files, but use lld for linking. lld is patched with enzyme to generate AD code
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=${LLD} -flto -Xclang -new-struct-path-tbaa")

include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SRC_FILES src/*.cpp src/maths/*.cpp)

add_library(descriptor SHARED ${SRC_FILES})

# pass linking to lld, with enzyme plugin
target_link_options(descriptor PRIVATE "LINKER:--lto-legacy-pass-manager")
target_link_options(descriptor PRIVATE "LINKER:-mllvm=-load=${ENZYME_LIB}/LLDEnzyme-${LLVM_MAJOR_VERSION}.dylib")
target_link_options(descriptor PRIVATE "LINKER:-mllvm=-enzyme-loose-types")


Now in Linux above file works fine (if I replace .dylib with .so), but on Mac I get:
ld64.lld: error: unknown argument '-mllvm=-load=/usr/local/lib/LLDEnzyme-13.dylib'
ld64.lld: error: unknown argument '-mllvm=-enzyme-loose-types'

I also tried removing = between -mllvm and -load, but same issue,
ld64.lld: error: unknown argument '-mllvm -load=/usr/local/lib/LLDEnzyme-13.dylib'
ld64.lld: error: unknown argument '-mllvm -enzyme-loose-types'

The full verbose command is,
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm@13/13.0.1_2/bin/clang++  -fuse-ld=lld -flto -Xclang -new-struct-path-tbaa -O3 -DNDEBUG -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Xlinker --lto-legacy-pass-manager -Xlinker "-mllvm -load=/usr/local/lib/LLDEnzyme-13.dylib" -Xlinker "-mllvm -enzyme-loose-types" -o libdescriptor.dylib -install_name @rpath/libdescriptor.dylib CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/Bispectrum.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/Descriptors.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/SOAP.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/SymmetryFunctions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/Xi.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/helper.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/maths/bessel_functions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/maths/clebsh_gordon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/maths/gamma.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/maths/gl_quad.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/maths/precomputed_bessel_zeros.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/maths/radial_basis_functions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/descriptor.dir/src/maths/spherical_harmonics.cpp.o


What exactly is not working with the code you provide in the question post? Does it choose proper if/else statement when configure on your machine? If yes, then appropriate parameters are passed at the link stage.

We need to see at least the complete linkage command that fails and its verbatim output.
Run VERBOSE=1 cmake --build <the_build_dir> and copy-paste that information
into your question.

I have updated the question to include, 1. full CMAKE file, 2. Error messages, 3. Verbose linker command. Please let me know if anything more is needed.

Previously you said "I get error that --lto-legacy-pass-manager is not a known option", but that does not appear in the diagnostics?

Sorry for the confusion. It was with a newer version of llvm, I saw on forums that they recommend switching to older versions (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/65085). Which gives the above error.

According to the linker's --help output the option is --mllvm, not -mllvm.
